# Why do I see two different session_id() values?

Tags: php, session, sessionid

I have a little script that works with session id values. When i want to insert the `session_id()` data to to my db, I see a value of something like `567` in the table. But, when i want to echo the same data using `session_id()` function, I see a hashed value consisting of 32 chars like `d6fc8fe0c82307cc97dd2a0e94c9bb56`.

What is the reason of this? Is this some kinda security issue with the PHP ?
How can i get the same value?

Here is the code:

```
$mysessid = session_id();

$sql = "INSERT into `mytable` (session_id) values('$mysessid')";
// when i use this sql to add the value into the db, i see a value like "7" or "251" etc in the table.

echo $mysessid;
// it outputs a hashed value like "d6fc8fe0c82307cc97dd2a0e94c9bb56"

// two different outputs...
```

Comment: Without code? I think it's global warming!

Comment: What kind of type do you use in db to store the session_id?

Comment: This seems more like a bug in your code, than an issue with PHP. Please provide some example code.

Comment: Sorry about that.. I added some code above.. I hope, I have explained..

Comment: Do you use an int type in your database for session_id?

Comment: Yes, I do.  That was the reason i guess. Noe i changed it to the varchar and will try again. Is it ok to use varchar? @Oliver

Comment: Thank you guys, changing the data type solved the problem. Sorry for bothering you.

Comment: Maybe it is better to use char(32), because in most cases it is faster than varchar in cases where the value is always the same length.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like your database structure is not formatted for an hex string. What type of field are you using for field session_id?